# Definite Sum of Confluent Hypergeometric involving power function

Tags: calculus, special-functions, summation, power-series

I find it difficult to evaluate the following definite sum:

$$ \sum _{k=1}^K \frac{_1F_1[k,1,x]} {2^k} $$

Thank you for your time

Comment: Evaluate to what form? $_1F_1(k,1,x)$ is a $(k-1)$th degree polynomial times $e^x$. Therefore the sum will necessarily be a $(K-1)$th degree polynomial times $e^x$.

Comment: Closed form if possible. Thank you O.L.

Comment: What definition are you using for the Laguerre polynomials? I'm not familiar with any that allows for a negative index.

Comment: I have used the identity connecting the Confluent Hypergeometric with b=1 with the Laguerre polynomial, based on wolframalpha. I revised the question, to be more general. Thank you Spencer.

Answer (score 2):

In view of many other analogous questions of the OP, it is difficult to expect a satisfactory answer here. As I said in my comment, the result is a $(K-1)$th degree polynomial times $e^x$. I don't understand what can be simpler nor what can be simplified but will try to make this claim more explicit below.

---

First note that 
$$_1F_1(k,1,x)=e^x _1F_1(1-k,1,-x)=e^{x}L_{k-1}(-x),$$
where $L_k(x)$ denotes $k$th Laguerre polynomial. So the sum of the question is 
\begin{align}
S_K=e^{x}\sum_{k=1}^K\frac{L_{k-1}(-x)}{2^k}&=\frac12 e^x\sum_{n=0}^{K-1}\frac{L_n(-x)}{2^n}=\\
&=\frac12 e^x\sum_{n=0}^{K-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{2^{n}k!}{n \choose k}=\\
&=\frac12 e^x\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\sum_{n=k}^{K-1}\frac{1}{2^n}{n \choose k}=\\
&=\frac12 e^x\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\left(2-2^{1-K}{K \choose k}{}_2F_1(-k,1,K-k+1;-1)\right).
\end{align}
Thus we obtain a polynomial representation with explicit coefficients.

---

**P.S.** Of course, as $K\rightarrow\infty$, a simpler representation can be obtained using the generating function of Laguerre polynomials
$$G(x,t)=\frac{1}{1-t}\exp\left\{-\frac{xt}{1-t}\right\}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}L_n(x)t^n.$$
Namely:
$$ S_{\infty}=\frac{e^{x}}{2}G\left(-x,\frac12\right)=e^{2x}.$$
However, for finite $K$ "exponential $\times$ polynomial" can only be "exponential $\times$ polynomial". It cannot eventually become a sine of $18^{\circ}$ or square root of $x^2+1$ or anything else like that.

Comment: Dear O.L., after your advising and suggestions I was (finally) able to reach to the Laguerre transformation suggested above. In any case, do you think that we could apply the formulas in chapter 5.3 of Marichev/Prudnikov Vol 3, to reach to final formula without involving the sum? I know that the second term in the Hypergeometric is the difficult part. To be honest, my first goal was to get rid of the summation.. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @dioxen After a quick look at Chapter 5.3, it doesn't seem it contains a formula that can transform your sum into a more complicated hypergeometric function. Personally, I don't even understand why would one want to do it: the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{K-1} 2^{-n} L_n(x)$ is a simper expression anyway, both mathematically and lexicographically.

Comment: Currently my primary goal is to avoid the sum, even if I go to a more complicated Hypergeometric function. I am currently looking on the related formulas for breaking the final sum that you kindly provided. Indeed, the sum that you provided is more complicated compared to the first one, so, I hope that it is more easy to handle in order to avoid the sum.

Comment: Dear O.L., the reason for trying to avoid the sum is that is included in another sum and I need to numerically evaluate an infinity sum (which takes a long time). Please advise:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451024/double-summation-involving-confluent-hypergeometric-factorial-and-power-functio

Comment: Dear @dioxen , I will be busy the next week but then will try to look at your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time O.L.